# Pivot this table in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this data here, image follows:

[image: This data]

I need to pivot the table and the expected output should be:

```
Description  From     To   2021-11-01
A             A        X   VALUE COLUMN
B             B        P   VALUE COLUMN
C             D        T   VALUE COLUMN
```

I already have tried below logic:

```
final_data.pivot_table(index=[['Description', 'From', 'To']], columns='Date', values=['Value'], aggfunc=len).reset_index()
```

This throws an error:

> Grouper and axis must be same length

I don't need agg function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a 2D list as index? Try: `final_data.pivot_table(index=['Description', 'From', 'To'], columns='Date', values=['Value'], aggfunc=len).reset_index()`. Also please provide a minimal **dummy** reproducible input. Not an image.

Comment: Regarding `aggfunc` why did you use `len` in the first place? what are you trying to do? Do you have duplicated indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue likely comes from the nested list used as value of the `index` parameter.

Use a simple list:

```
final_data.pivot_table(index=['Description', 'From', 'To'], columns='Date', values='Value', aggfunc=len).reset_index()
```